# Make Azure App Service forward proxy after moving

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have an Azure App service say appInIndia.azurewebsites.net. Now I need to move this application to another region because some data residency issues, so URL become appInUae.azurewebsites.net.

Now, both apps are working fine. But I wanna redirect all traffic from appInIndia.azurewebsites.net to appInUae.azurewebsites.net using forward proxy. Is it possible in Azure or I need to create a new app that make appInIndia.azurewebsites.net as a forward proxy?

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this is to add a redirect rule to your `web.config` file.

Comment: `<system.webServer>
   <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.contoso.com/" />
</system.webServer>`

Comment: You can also  use the Front Door for the traffic routing between primary and secondary region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new application using YARP which act as a reverse proxy and deployed this app in `appInIndia.azurewebsites.net` which route all traffic to `appInUae.azurewebsites.net`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Azure Font Door with VNET configuration
Azure Font door can do the same job as YARP + load balancing + SSL termination and many more, but its paid service.
VNET will route traffic via Microsoft network which has lower latency.
If you use YARP , you will obviously need to host it in another web app which will cost you few bucks